# Cannot connect to Oracle (oci8) with Apache (FPM). PHP 7.x CLI is OK

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oci8

I made a PHP script that connect to Oracle (oci8 extension). It works well when i run it with CLI mode (*# php test-oracle.php*)

But the same script opened in the the browser (Apache + PHP 7.x FPM) do not works and i got this error:

```
oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries
```

I read and follow many things that i found in forums (also in stackoverflow) but nothing work for apache.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Apache 2.4.33 / PHP 7.1.18

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check whether your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Apache/PHP is correct as the error suggests?

Comment: @gvenzl Yes i tried to add in many place without sucess, /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf, /etc/environment, /etc/apache2/envvars and also in /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini. I still have the same error in browser. I use oracle instantclient installed in /opt/oracle_instantclient. This is the path i used for LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Don't understand why is not working..

Comment: Have a look with `phpinfo();` whether or not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is actually set for your PHP process. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345515/oracle-11g-php-oci-connect-fails-ocienvnlscreate and https://community.oracle.com/thread/4081480

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g PHP oci\_connect fails OCIEnvNlsCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345515/oracle-11g-php-oci-connect-fails-ocienvnlscreate)

Comment: When you added it to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf` did you then run `ldconfig`?  Is /opt/oracle_instantclient readable by the Apache process?

Comment: @ChristopherJones Yes i did ldconfig after. But my /opt/oracle_instantclient folder and files are owned by root, files is 644 and dir 755. Is it enough?

Comment: @gvenzl Yes LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in phpinfo() with /opt/oracle_instantclient because i enter manually in /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and so answer to my self.

My Oracle Instant Client version was little too old (11.2.x) and i updated to a new one (12.1.x) and follow a standard guide (see below) for my case. And now it's works with apache without nothing else.

https://gist.github.com/hewerthomn/81eea2935051eb2500941a9309bca703

So i guess was some permission problem or something like that with this library.

Again thanks for your help!